# Eigenvalues of a discretized system

Tags: control-theory

I have to show that the dynamic matrix of a time-invariant discrete-time system has
eigenvalues located at $1+\lambda_cT$, if the discretization was performed by the explicit Euler
method. This should be shown for an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix $A$. For the explicit Euler method the dynamic matrix is computed via $I + AT$, where:

$I$ ...the identity matrix

$\lambda_c$ ...eigenvalues of the continuous time system

$A$ ...dynamic matrix

$T$  ...discretization time.

My approach:

For the eigenvalues, we want to compute the determinants and set them to zero:

$$
det((I + AT) - \lambda_d I) = 0
$$

for the discrete system, where $\lambda_d$ denotes the eigenvalues of the discrete case. Then we have:

$$
det(A - \lambda_cI) = 0
$$

for the continuous system.

I thought of just comparing the two equations and solve for $\lambda_d$, to get $1 + \lambda_cT$, which does not quite work. I am bit stuck here and would be glad about any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $\lambda_d=1+\lambda_c\,T$ into expression inside the determinant of the equation for the discrete time eigenvalue problem yields

\begin{align}
(I + A\,T) - \lambda_d\,I &= (I + A\,T) - (1+\lambda_c\,T)\,I \\ 
&= I + A\,T - I - \lambda_c\,T\,I \\
&= (A - \lambda_c\,I)\,T.
\end{align}

So as long as $T\neq0$ then $\det((I + A\,T) - \lambda_d\,I)=0$ is equivalent to $\det(A - \lambda_c\,I)=0$ when using $\lambda_d=1+\lambda_c\,T$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lambda_c$ is the eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax = \lambda_c x$ and by induction:
$$
A^n x = A^{n-1}\lambda_cx = \cdots =  A\lambda_c^{n-1} x = \lambda_c^n x
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
and the relationship between the continuous time state matrix $A$ and its discrete counterpart $A_d$ is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization):
$$
A_d = e^{AT}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (AT)^k
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
then
$$
A_dx= e^{AT}x= \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (AT)^k \right)x = \\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} T^kA^kx \stackrel{\eqref{eq1}}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} T^k\lambda_c^kx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (T\lambda_c)^kx \stackrel{\eqref{eq2}}= e^{T\lambda_c}x
\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
Equation \eqref{eq3} states that $e^{T\lambda_c}$ is the eigenvalue of $A_d$:
$$
\lambda_d = e^{T\lambda_c} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (T\lambda_c)^k
\tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
Taking only first two terms of the sum in \eqref{eq4} will give (this is known as the Euler method):

$$
\lambda_d = e^{T\lambda_c} \approx 1+T\lambda_c
$$